# Cordova 1.7 Build Succeeds on Simulator, Fails on Device

Tags: cordova

I have been using PhoneGap 1.0 for a long time now and it works with no problems on the simulator and on my device. (ie. I did the provisioning profile etc.)  Now I am trying the same thing with Phonegap/Cordova 1.7 and the build succeeds on the simulator but not on the provisioned test device (iPhone 3GS - iOS 4.3).  Can't figure out what's going on.  This is on a clean new project.

The error message I get on the build fail is:
`Command /usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this Phonegap/Cordova problem by changing the value of the Valid Architectures found in Project > Build Settings > Architectures from the default "armv6 armv7" to "armv7".